# How to override Module js file in Joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, cms

I would like to minify a js file of a Joomla module. For example, the file:

> joomla_site/modules/mod_module/tmpl/js/file.js

which has been copied to following location:

> joomla_site/templates/my_template/html/mod_module/tmpl/js/file.js

It's been minified. I reloaded my site, and there was no change. The site is still using the un-minified js file. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the module is using the following method to import the script:

```
JHtml::_('script', 'path/to/file.js', array(), true);
```

**Not using `$doc->script()`**

Then you need to copy the file to the following path:

> joomla-site/templates/my_template/html/mod_module/file.js

The path **shouldn't** have `tmpl/js/` in it.

Answer (score 1):

If it's your own custom module - go with another answer solution, but if it's not yours - I suggest you to go with JCH Optimizer - free version fully covers your needs.

Comment: JCH Optimize is for caching, not overriding JS files

Comment: JCH Optimize is for caching, minifying and compiling to 1 file all CSS and all JS to another. This man wants to minify js - so it's his option, believe me. Used it at least 20 times already.

Comment: @Alexandr: I would suggest to complete your answer by adding this type of comment in your answer - explaining why you suggest JCH optimize and what can be achieved by using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by including Javascript file in footer so that it will overwrite the file.

1. Create a new file called footer.php in **/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/** directory:
2. In **/libraries/joomla/document/document.php** add after

   `public $_scripts = array();`
   this
   `public $_footer_scripts = array();`
3. Add method **addFooterScript()** after the **addScript()** method

   ```
   function addFooterScript($url, $type = "text/javascript", $defer = false, $async = false) {
       $this->_footer_scripts[$url]['mime'] = $type;
       $this->_footer_scripts[$url]['defer'] = $defer;
       $this->_footer_scripts[$url]['async'] = $async;
       return $this;
   }
   ```
4. In index.php in you template folder add just before the  tag 
   `<jdoc:include type="footer" />`
5. Done!

   Now in layouts inside your template's folder you can use the following code to add javascript files to footer:

   ```
   $doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
   $doc->addFooterScript('JavaScript_File_Path.js');
   ```

For more instructions check this - [Javascript files includes in footer](https://github.com/rishiv3/joomla-adding-javascript-file-in-the-footer)